# How to show currency symbol instead of currency name?

Tags: treeview, odoo, openerp-8

I created a module to show related Purchase Orders from projects:

[image]

After clicking the `Compras` (Purchases) button a custom tree view is shown with the `currency_id` field:

[image]

Is there a way to show the symbol of the currency instead of the name? Something like you would do for example using Django: `currency_id.symbol`. Even better, I want to drop the `currency_id` field and prepend the currency symbol in the total amount, is that possible? Something like `S/. 336.30` in the `amount_total` field.

Here's my tree view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        ....
        ....
        <record id="purchase_order_project_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">purchase.order.tree</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Compras"
                    colors="grey:state=='cancel';blue:state in ('wait','confirmed');red:state in ('except_invoice','except_picking')">
                    <field name="name" string="Reference"/>
                    <field name="date_order" />
                    <field name="partner_id"/>
                    <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
                    <field name="currency_id" />
                    <field name="amount_total" />
                    <field name="state"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        ....
        ....
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Any feedback from the downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field called currency_symbol in your module (py) that gets the currency symbol when the currency changues with an on_changue to the currency. So you bring that field to the view, you cant directly do it from the XML.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the that button to get the tree get listed, you can override the "name_get" method of "Currency" and fetch the "currency symbol" instead of name. For this you can pass a flag in the context to limit this modification specific to your module only.

Hope this helps!!.